# Confused with math notation

Tags: notation

I'm reading a Reinforcement Learning book where the following is stated.

[image]

$$
Q_t(a)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{t-1} R_i \cdot 1A_t=a }{\sum_{i=1}^{t-1} \cdot 1A_t=a}
$$

I understand the summing section. So for example, ignoring

$$
1A_i=a
$$

if i: { 1,2,3,4   }  and t=3 then qt(a) = sum(1, 2) / sum( 1, 2).

How does

$$
1A_i=a
$$

impact the calculation?

Comment: That's an indicator random variable with two possible values 0,1. As long as A_i = a, it's value is 1, otherwise it's 0.

Comment: $t$ can't be 3 in your given case.

Answer (score 4):

$1_{A_i=a}$ is a notation for the characteristic function of the set $\{i; A_i=a \}$, that is:
$$1_{A_i=a}=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $i\in $ } \{i; A_i=a \}\\
0, & \text{if $i \notin \{i; A_i=a \}$}
\end{cases}$$

Basically, it means you should sum only over the indexes $i$ such that $A_i=a$.

Comment: if instead of $1_{A_i=a}$ the following is defined : $3_{A_i=a}$ then are the valid values just 3 or 0 instead of 1 or 0 ?

Comment: @blue-sky What is $3_{A_i=a}$? This is not a standard notation.